How to have boot page like manjaro when selecting the operating system in Ubuntu?
I recently tested manjaro gnome edition, and after installing the boot or grub not sure what it is the page when we turn on the computer an select the operating system. i like it better than the default from ubuntu. I have ubuntu 24.04
I think is better the manjato boot page because the letters are bigger and is centered, and have a nice image, that possibly is on ubuntu. And after shutdown the computer or restart, the computer log to the last operating system what can be convinent.
And so have a better presentation and works better.
I want to install the same boot or grub mechanism on my laptop but dont know the name or if actually the same mechanism exists on ubuntu.
Can anyone tell me if there exists on ubuntu ? and if so what is the name and possibly tell me how to install it.(if i can use synaptic i just need to type the name, because i already install synaptic)

You can apply Manjaro's GRUB theme as fetched from Manjaro's repository and add the minimal required configuration (use Manjaro's GRUB theme, show the menu, auto-select the last booted entry, automatically boot the auto-selected entry after 5 seconds) to the installed GRUB to make it look and behave exactly as Manjaro's (to remove Manjaro's logo, see the last section of the answer).

Create a folder to store GRUB themes in /boot/grub if it doesn't exist:
sudo mkdir -p /boot/grub/themes


Download Manjaro's GRUB theme from Manjaro's repository1 and decompress and extract the usr/share/grub/themes/manjaro folder in the compressed archive to /boot/grub/themes, all at once:
wget -O - https://mirror.fcix.net/manjaro/stable/extra/x86_64/grub-theme-manjaro-20.2-16-any.pkg.tar.zst |
    unzstd --stdout - |
    sudo tar -x -C/boot/grub/themes --strip-components=4 -f- usr/share/grub/themes/manjaro


Edit /etc/default/grub so that GRUB will mimic the behavior of GRUB on Manjaro. Run sudo nano /etc/default/grub and make sure that all the key / value pairs listed below exist and are set to their specific value (on Ubuntu 24.04 with a default /etc/default/grub you'll have to add GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT and GRUB_THEME and change the others):

GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_THEME=/boot/grub/themes/manjaro/theme.txt
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu


Update GRUB:
sudo update-grub




To remove Manjaro's logo, remove the following section from /boot/grub/themes/manjaro/theme.txt:
# Logo image
+ image {
        left = 30%-250
        top = 10%-30
    file = "logo.png"
}


1. The file's name will change if the package is updated; so if the link breaks, visit https://mirror.fcix.net/manjaro/stable/extra/x86_64 and change grub-theme-manjaro-20.2-16-any.pkg.tar.zst accordingly; this will download the theme using mirror.fcix.net, a US-based mirror; if the link breaks or you want to use a different mirror, replace the base URI mirror.fcix.net/manjaro with the base URI of an available mirror of your choice: https://repo.manjaro.org/

is it grub the same as boot?i am confused if you understand what i mean.i meant the menu selecting the operating system and not the user and desktop enviroment like kde and gnome. i am saying also this because i have use grun but dont really undertand what is named for

@TiagoEarth GRUB is a boot loader, a piece of software that is used to boot the operating system. Both Manjaro and Ubuntu happen to use GRUB (at least by default), so all it takes is to modify the installed GRUB to have it look and behave the same as in Manjaro. It would've been more complex if the two used a different boot loader. But yes, I understand what you want to change, and that is GRUB, not GDM or some other display manager.

@TiagoEarth Basically, this is how GRUB looks on Manjaro. If you go through the steps listed above, GRUB will end up looking exactly the same, as it will start using the exact same theme.

i did the steps and changed to look like manjaro even the behavior, but would like to have a different theme that didnt said manjaro because it doesnt make sense for me. how can i change to a theme for ubuntu or one that doesnt say anything i would prefer one that didnt said anything

i imagine is in this GRUB_THEME=/boot/grub/themes/manjaro/theme.txt i must change

@TiagoEarth Yes, see my updated answer

You can install the Grub themes by vinceluice.

Image source
Open a terminal and enter the following commands:
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/vinceliuice/grub2-themes
cd grub2-themes
sudo ./install.sh -b -t stylish

Then reboot.
The commands above will install the "Stylish" theme, but some other themes are available as well (see image below). Check out GitHub for more details.
Here is how to set a custom background.

source

i tried to copy and paste the 3 lines and didnt work after pressing enter on the terminal and then line by line and appear 1 error for the second and third and also didnt worked

I updated the commands. Can you post what is the error message? You will have to use them line by line
